# How to transform null XML element to JSON

Tags: mule, dataweave, mule4

I have to transform xml to json.The xml element is

Input:

```
<XML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ABC xsi:nil="true"/>
    <DEF/>
</XML>
```

dataweave code:

```
%dw2.0
output application/json skipNullOn="everywhere"
---
payload.XML
```

Expected Output(
json):

```
{
"ABC": null
}
```

Getting Output(json):

```
{

}
```

This "ABC" element is a part of the xml payload where I am also using skipNullOn="everywhere" for other null elements. But I don't want that skipNullOn="everywhere" to apply to the element which has "xsi:nil="true"(ABC). I cannot remove skipNullOn="everywhere" as I want to allow only those null elements in which **xsi:nil="true"** is set.

Comment: Did you try it?  I do not believe you need to do anything other than use the field, JSON should set it to `null`.  At least that is what I get when I try it.

Comment: Yes @[George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3078986/george), you are right, but actually I am using skipNullOn="everywhere" in the script so it is taking <ABC xsi:nil="true"/> also as a null value and skipping it, but I want it not to skip. I want only a particular element in which xsi:nil="true" is set, not to be skipped as null while transforming to json.

Comment: Then you will have to do it explicitly, `payload.ABC == null` should do it.

Comment: but how do I know which element has ```xsi:nil="true"``` set? Is there any way to access the value of ```xsi:nil``` ?

Comment: Provide with you input sample data and the expected output, otherwise we will keep going back and forth

Comment: [George](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3078986/george) I have edited the question and made input and expected output clear, please help me with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223569/discussion-between-amer-sufi-and-george).

Comment: Thank you for add the sample data and the expected output--AFAIK there is no way to make the distinction between a tag that has the `xsi:nil="true"` and one that doesn't.